# \hfill underlining in a tabular environment

Tags: tables

I would like to make a name and address fill-in-the-blank in a neat rectangle with a lined space where the information should be filled in.  At first I came up with this:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{NAME\underline{\hspace{15em}}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{ADDRESS\underline{\hspace{15em}}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{CITY\underline{\hspace{15em}}} \\
STATE\underline{\hspace{3em}} & ZIP\underline{\hspace{8em}}
\end{tabular}
```

But this yields a ragged right edge and tinkering with the \hspace{} parameters is a non-starter.  I tried this:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{NAME\underline{\hspace{15em}}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{ADDRESS\underline{\h fill}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{CITY\underline{\hfill}} \\
STATE\underline{\hspace{3em}} & ZIP\underline{\hfill}
\end{tabular}
```

But I get no underlines at all with the \hfills.  I don't want to simply make this a tabular with \hlines because that will result in underlined field names or gaps between the field names and the underlining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is far easier to leave the guess-work to TeX. In the example below I've fixed the `tabular` to a single `p`aragraph column of width `20em`. Rules are inserted using leaders (via `\hrulefill`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{20em}@{}}
  NAME~\hrulefill \\
  ADDRESS~\hrulefill \\
  CITY~\hrulefill \\
  STATE~\hrulefill\quad ZIP~\hrulefill\hrulefill
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

The rule associated with `ZIP` is twice that of `STATE`, as suggested by the double `\hrulefill`. The total width of the table is `20em`, since padding on either end has been removed with `@{}`.